# Multiple access rules to pages in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, passwords, login-control

I came to a problem:

I have a project with successful Login mechanics.
I used Login Control and then wrote code to check if user and password from Login Control match the one in DB.

On matching pair, this happens:

```
if (authenticated)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginControl.UserName, LoginControl.RememberMeSet);
        }
```

and once logged-in I can access/get redirected to Members.aspx in separated folder and with

```
    <authorization>
         <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

in web.config I prevent anon users to access this folder.

But I have to separate Members folder from Administration folder.

I have extra column in Users table in DB that tells me if user is Admin or not.

How could I give Admin users extra rights or limit ordinary logged in users from accessing Administration folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and the code above works you can deny to certain pages like this..

```
<location path="AdminPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admins" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The deny users = "*" will deny everyone unless they have access. This is how many do it in theirs. Hope this helps.

Then on login you can check to see if that user is an admin or not. If they are, they can access that page, if they aren't, they can't. I'm using Active Directory currently but you can use SQL or Linq to Sql to check to see if they are an admin or not.

EDIT: Here are some links that might help you in the right direction.

[Link One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx) this one is "outdated" but it will show you how it was recommended before.

[Link Two](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342061/Understanding-ASP-NET-Roles-and-Membership-A-Begin)

[Link Three](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) This one shows you how to set up an SQLMemberShipProvider.

The third one is the one I would suggest exploring. I use an ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider with my applications at work. I think this is going to be your best chance.

Comment: Awesome, was hoping for something like that. How do I set role though?

Comment: Just have in mind that I'm not using WSAT ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342061/Understanding-ASP-NET-Roles-and-Membership-A-Begin )..

Comment: That is going to get a bit more complicated. You will have to check to see if the user is an admin on page load. If the user is not an admin, then you have to redirect them to a "Not Authorized Page." As far as I know, I don't think you can use "Allow Roles" in the webconfig. If you do the sql approach, you will have to change the 'deny users="*"' to deny users="?". Basically you will allow each user access to all the page, but use your SQL to verify if they are an admin or not. If not, redirect them.

Comment: Is that secure enough to prevent any attacks with altering data (cookies, session)?

Comment: Look at my edit. I have provided you with some links that may be useful. And to answer your question, it would not be 100% effective without other security checks.